# How to use json variable in shell script file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, json, packer

I would like to use this json file to get jenkins version and java version numbers to include my `script.sh` file. How do we do that?

I tried `` {{user `java_version`}} `` but it did not work.

- `variable.json` file

  ```json
  {
      "region": "us-east-1",
      "jenkins_version": "2.263.4",
      "java_version": "1.8.0"

  }
  ```
- `script.sh` file

  ```bash
  #!/bin/bash
  sudo yum update -y
  sudo yum install wget -y
  sudo yum install   java-{{user `java_version`}}-openjdk-devel -y
  sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo
  sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key
  sudo yum install -y jenkins-{{user `java_version`}}
  sudo systemctl start jenkins
  sudo systemctl status jenkins
  #Get auth password from jenkins master
  echo "authpwd="$(sudo cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword)
  ```

Comment: Try this site: https://www.ultralinux.org/post/json-bash/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `jq` command it is a command line json parser.  You can pull any field you would like.

https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-jq/

For example this will return the java_version number.

```
cat variable.json | jq .java_version
```

If you prefer using core commands so you don't have to install anything you can use this command.

```
cat input | grep java_version | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Shorter version of the above command before someone says you don't have to cat into grep.

```
grep java_version variable.json | awk '{print $NF}'
```

EDIT: Another option would be.

```
sudo yum install -y jenkins-$(grep java_version variable.json | awk '{print $NF}' | sed 's/"//g')-openjdk
```

Comment: Hey jason, thanks for the commands. What i am really looking for to embed it into this line 
sudo yum install -y jenkins-{{user `java_version`}}     how am i supposed to that?

Comment: `sudo yum install -y jenkins-$(cat input | jq .java_version | sed 's/"//g')` This will return something like `jenkins-1.8.0` I am not familiar with how the jenkins packages are named you may have to add `-openjdk` or something like that to the end.i

Comment: I added another example to the answer at the bottom it shows how you would add something to the end of the version number if you need to.

Comment: Some people might look at commands like this an say there too long or oh I can do that with just awk yes it is possible to do this with just awk but the syntax is much harder to remember and this way I thinks show just why Linux/Unix shine commands that do one thing and do it well.

Comment: You can use `jq`'s `-r` switch to output raw values (without quotes) ex. `jenkins-$(jq -r .java_version variable.json)`